# EF4 + MVVM - Expose entities in ViewModel?

Tags: .net, wpf, silverlight, entity-framework, mvvm

I've played around with some different implementations of Model-View-ViewModel and consistently come across a situation where I am not sure of the correct way to proceed. I know one of the goals of MVVM is to decouple the View from the application logic so that the logic can be tested without the presence of a View. Putting the logic in a ViewModel which has no dependencies on the View solves this problem. Great. Even better if the Model can be decoupled from the ViewModel in such a way that it can be mocked.

So my question is, should the ViewModel decouple the Model from the View? In other words, is it "ok" to expose EntityFramework entities to the View through the ViewModel? For example, say there is a combobox in the view where the user can choose a State for an address. In the AddressViewModel, should State be exposed as a real entity-type property, or should it be exposed as a StateViewModel? If it should be a StateviewModel-typed property, I don't understand how the underlying model should be managed within the AddressViewModel.State setter (because what is being set in the property is a StateViewModel and not a State entity).

It seems to me that this could go either way, but seems more consistent to never expose the model directly to the view. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of the view model is to decouple the view from the data model.  If there's no functionality in the view that's coupled to the data model, no view model is necessary.

If you have an object in the data model whose properties don't change after it's created, and that the view is not going to modify, and that can be presented in the UI without formatting or conversion, then you're not coupling any of its functionality to the view by exposing it directly.  You don't need a view model for this.

In your example, you probably can get away without creating a `StateViewModel` class, since such a class wouldn't really do anything.

Comment: That is true in theory, but in practice sometimes things are not as constant as people (the developers among them) would like to think, for example the list of states might be expanded in the future to include other countries, etc...

Comment: That's not the kind of change that would have an impact on this decision.  Adding new states to the list doesn't create the requirement that its properties be editable in the UI.

Answer (score 4):

You should strive to completely decouple your model from your view, this should be a goal, you might meet it, or you might not, but still that should be your goal.

Specifically your question deals with a list of constants (more or less), which is an easy case. Correct me if I'm wrong here, but you probably have a `States` table with a `code` and a `name` for each state, and then you have another table with a foreign key to the former.

In this scenario it is best to load up and create the `StateViewModel` list once during application initialization, and then deal with the foreign key value (the state `code` as it were) throughout the application instead of the `StateViewModel` objects themselves. The properties you should use are the `SelectedValue` and `SelectedValuePath` of the `ComboBox`, example:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{x:Static StateViewModel.StaticList}"
          SelectedValue="{Binding StateForeignKey}"
          SelectedValuePath="code"
          DisplayMemberPath="name" />
```

This will populate the `ComboBox` with `StateViewModel` objects (which were created using a now-disposed context), but will pass the selected item's `code` property on to the bound field `StateForeignKey`, additionally, the `ComboBox` will display the `name` property so that it's human-readable.

Answer (score 1):

I bind the entity directly to my view via the viewmodel unless I have to add specific properties such as IsSelected etc... for treeviews.  If I have to add addition properties then I have the viewmodel wrap each entity property.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you can't expose Entity in ViewModel is because **you should not pollute the Entity with view specific code** such as IDataErrorInfo, INotifyPropertyChanged, IEditableObject etc.

Entity is application core and should be POCO, can be reused in every type of application. For example if your develop an application that accessible via Mobile, Web and Desktop you don't need to create Entity for each type of application.

decoupling reason? sorry, but i'm not agree, because i don't see any beneficial by decouple Model and ViewModel because unit test will work fine with or without Entity inside ViewModel.

**UPDATE**

sorry i forgot that you used EF4. EF4 entity is support INotifyPropertyChanged by default so it will be acceptable to expose your entity on ViewModel.